# nested if function transformation for linearization, solver optimization

Tags: optimization, solver

I have 10 nested if functions. I'm trying to transform nonsmooth and non linear function to a linear function. In order to do that, I need to transform nested if functions to a linear format by adding binary variables. It is easy if there is only 1 if statement. What about more than one. Thanks in advance for your responds.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may not still be an issue for you, but I just saw this post today. Manually linearizing nested IF statements can be quite a challenge. LINDO Systems has an Excel add-in solver named What'sBest that can internally linearize nested IF statements. This can allow What'sBest to solve the resulting model as a mixed integer linear program.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Is it a student version? If so, there may be variable limit. That case causes not to use if statements because of employing extra artificial 0-1 variables. I encountered the same case when I used frontline solver student version...

Comment: The version that can be downloaded from our website defaults to a limited capacity version lacking a license key. However, I can set you up with a temporary key with no capacity restrictions if you wanted to try it out. And, if you are a student/professor using it for educational purposes/research we can set you up with a longer term license.